# Bootstrap 3 - jumbotron background image javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a jumbotron where the background is a slideshow but the foreground is a static image. I am trying to copy http://okkienergy.com/ without using flash. I thought maybe I could use javascript to animate the background image but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this fiddle, it might help 
`[http://jsfiddle.net/srd76/36/]`